# React - change/replace string parameter of function

Tags: reactjs

I have installed React/NPM library to my project that has to set configuration options with the use of its own method.
I would like to ask if it is possible in React to change string value that is used in function by another function directly?
Because the library method only accepts string values and must be using it all the time.
If not is it maybe possible to replace line of code with function?
I would like to have a function that change it by submit of some form somewhere in the website.

Please see the example to understand better what I want to do:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Config } from '@example-library';

function App() {
 
  React.useEffect(() => {
    Config.setOfferId('abcd1234');
  }, []);
return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <p>Hello world</p>
      </div>
  );
}
```

I am referring to **Config.setOfferId('abcd1234');** - I either want to replace 'abcd1234' with 'zxyv0987' or change the whole line from Config.setOfferId('abcd1234'); to Config.setOfferId('zxyv0987');
I just don't know what are my options and React limits.
Could you please help me?

EDIT: I changed the Config.setEnv to Config.setOfferId - to emphasis another aspect and get better answer as I do not really want to change environment rather other options that this method has inbuilt.

Answer (score 0):

use useState to handle the variable and then control the update of useEffect by adding it as a dependency to the dependency array -> [];

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Config } from '@example-library';

function App() {

  const [offerId, setOfferId] = useState('abcd1234');
 
  useEffect(() => {
    Config.setOfferId(offerId);
  }, [offerId]);
  
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <p>Hello world</p>
          <button onClick={() => setOfferId('anything you want')}>Click Me </button> 
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the idea is actually to be able change not only environment on go while the app runs. There is also other settings in the this Config method like for example "offerID" and this is actually what I want to be able to change. The environment was just example, but it will usually stay on sandbox and not be changed. The question is therefor if it is possible to change the string?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Dynamic Data which sits on the server side. You would create these IDs on a server and the front end code would then fetch the ID at another time. Because the server is a single source of truth, you only need to worry about setting the data once on the server and all the client's will have the same string. Unless you are going for a decentralised architecture (like GunJS), I would advise creating a simple express API, setting a value in a database, creating a endpoint that gets this string from the db, and then fetching the endpoint from your react app

Comment: Thank you for your comment, well what I really intend to achieve is to change the data as I explained solely for the purpose on switching the config on go for automated tests. This version of app I am working on will be kinda testing demo app, not really meant for end users.

Comment: So change the variables based on the environment you are in? Like a testing environment?

Comment: No, to be able to change manually the variables, from i.e. form on submit - you enter OfferID and submit it by button from form and it changes and reaload the website, the environment pretty much will always stay on the same value

Comment: ok got it. Updated my answer